# How to read font family name in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, markers, font

I'm trying to set symbology on a point layer in QGIS using a font marker.  I would like to use a font that contains symbols rather than normal characters.

[image]
The dropdown picker for font family seems to display the text using the style of the font.

[image]

This could be useful when trying to write a Word document or something.  However, it becomes really confusing when trying to pick amongst several symbolic fonts.

[image]

Is there a setting in QGIS that will display the font names using just a plain font without using the font itself to display it? I'm looking for the ability to read the fonts within the dropdown.

Answer (score 5):

The name of the font is also there with the style of the font, but you need to select the font first to see its name, as you can see below:

[image]

In order to see the names, first select the font style, then use the up and down arrows in your keyboard to see font names and not the style.

**Update**:

It is not a convenient solution, but you can use the following code to get all the names of font families using python, but not from inside QGIS. I run the code from outside QGIS as standalone script, because `Tkinter` is not available in my python path of QGIS:

```
import Tkinter
import tkFont

t = Tkinter.Toplevel()
fonts = tkFont.families()
t.destroy()

sort = sorted(fonts)
for font in sort:
    print font
```

I extracted part of the code from [here](https://anitagraser.com/2012/05/29/listing-available-fonts-for-pyprocessing/)

Comment: Thanks. I realised that (though didn't say so in my post). I was hoping for a way to see them all at a glance without having to select them.

Comment: OK, I got it, so you need to see list of font names not list of font styles.

Comment: That's exactly right.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  I may not have been clear in my comments.  Ideally, I'd like to see the list from within the dialog box.  It's difficult to choose a font when I don't know what it's called.  But +1 for the workaround.

Comment: You have been clear and I understood very well that you want to see the font names in the drop-down menu, but I think it is not possible, that is why I gave another option. It will better if the developers add this option in the settings in their next releases.